# echo $UID gives host ID and not container root user ID (docker/linux)

Tags: linux, docker

My current user ID on my host (ubuntu) is:

```
$ echo "Host UID = $UID"
Host UID = 1000
```

But when I run this docker container I get the same UID:

```
$ docker run --rm --name test-container centos:7.9.2009 /bin/bash -c "echo $UID"
1000
```

If I instead run the container interactively I get 0 as expected:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --name test-container centos:7.9.2009
[root@4a79cb82abec /]# echo $UID
0
```

Why do I get the wrong (my host user) UID when I run the container with `/bin/bash -c "echo $UID"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get `UID` from inside the container. However the variable `UID` is expanded on the host's shell itself.
Use single quote to avoid it getting expanded:

```
docker run --rm --name test-container centos:7.9.2009 /bin/bash -c 'echo $UID'
```